# Change Connection String based on App Location

Tags: c#

How can I change the connection string to my entity framework database, based on if it is debugging locally, or on the server. I want to use the internal IP address of the database when it is on the server to hopefully increase performance. I am hoping I will not have to change the connection string every time I want to publish the site.
I am using Visual Studo 11. I have not tried anything because I am not sure what the options are. I have been deploying to file system, but I will be doing web deploy in the near future.

Comment: How are you deploying? Which version of VS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [Web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx).

With it, you can replace values in the config file automatically based on the build configuration. Create a separate build configuration for the server if needed, or just use Release.

Comment: Man, beat me by 20 seconds. Last time I tried an answer this short though, SO converted it to a comment automatically.

Comment: I think SO also counts the links as characters in the answer, that's likely why this one got through :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use web.config transformations to specify which should be used in each situation. See this blog post for more information.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx

Basically, you'd specify your debug connection string in web.debug.config and your release in web.release.config.